# A Simple Logarithm Question

Tags: logarithms

Solve for $x$:  $\log_2 (2x+8)=3$

Correct Solution:
$2x+8=2^3$
$2x+8=8$
$2x=0$
$x=0$

Why doesn't this work:
$\log_2 (2x+8)=3$

Expand:
$\log_2(2x)+\log_28=3$
$\log_2(2x)+3=3$
$\log_2(2x)=0$
$2x=2^0$
$2x=1$
$x=1/2$

Thank you

Comment: That is not the rule for logarithms: $log_{2}(x+y)\neq log_{2}(x)+log_{2}(y)$ the actual rule is $log_{a}(xy)=log_{a}(x)+log_{a}(y)$.

Comment: of course! I must be going blind! thank you

Answer (score 1):

Note that 
$$\log_2(2x+8)\not=\log_2(2x)+\log_2(8).$$

We have $\log_2(2x)+\log_2(8)=\log_2(2x\color{red}{\times} 8)$.

Answer (score -1):

One more way: to make yr life easier use the property of yhe logsrithm:

$$
\log_a b = \frac{\ln b}{\ln a}
$$

wher3 ln is a natural log. After a bit of algebra exponentiate both sides.

Comment: Can you at least make this english? Even without the "language twirks" it's not really helpful, but like this it's simply bad.

Comment: 1) im writing from a cell phone, 2) my answr is correct and downvote is unmotivated

Comment: No, I gave you my motivation. Use proper english and I will remove it. BTW my cellphone requires more taps to enter "wher3" than to enter "where" - your argument is invalid.